# Apache Artemis unable to bind message successfully with Spring bases Artemis consumer

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Artemis Message producer java program :

```
initialContext = new InitialContext();

         // Step 2. Look-up the JMS topic
         Topic topic = (Topic) initialContext.lookup("topic/exampleTopic");

         // Step 3. Look-up the JMS connection factory
         ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

         // Step 4. Create a JMS connection
         connection = cf.createConnection();

         // Step 5. Set the client-id on the connection
         connection.setClientID("durable-client");

         // Step 6. Start the connection
         connection.start();

         // Step 7. Create a JMS session
         Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

         // Step 8. Create a JMS message producer
         MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(topic);
         TextMessage message1 = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message 1");
         // Step 11. Send the text message to the topic
         messageProducer.send(message1);
```

.....

client(using spring) ->

```
 @Bean("amqTransportConfiguration")
        public TransportConfiguration amqTransportConfiguration() {
            return new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), getParams("61616"));
        }


        @Bean("connectionFactory")
        public ConnectionFactory activeMQJMSConnectionFactory(@Qualifier("amqTransportConfiguration") TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration) throws JMSException {
            ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory activeMQJMSConnectionFactory =
                    new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory( false, transportConfiguration);
            activeMQJMSConnectionFactory.setPassword("xxxxx");
            activeMQJMSConnectionFactory.setUser("xxxx");
            activeMQJMSConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientServer0Id);
            return activeMQJMSConnectionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer1(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Consumer consumer, ObjectMessageConverter messageConverter, @Qualifier("topic") Topic topic) {
            return new DefaultMessageListenerContainerBuilder().connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                    .destination(topic)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter)
                    .messageListener(consumer)
                    .sessionAcknowledgeMode(1)
                    .pubSubDomain(true)
                    .subscriptionDurable(true)
                    .clientId(clientServer0Id)
                    .durableSubscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                    .build();
        }
```

ObjectMessageConverter ->

```
@Component
public class ObjectMessageConverter implements MessageConverter {

    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
        return session.createObjectMessage((Serializable) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
        if (message instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage) {
            ActiveMQTextMessage objMessage = (ActiveMQTextMessage) message;
            return ((ActiveMQTextMessage) message).getText();
        }
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        return textMessage.getText();
    }

}
```

---

When i am running the producer program send send a message to a topic, where client(spring part) is listening this topic, but it's unable to receive the message successfully.

get following trace in log  (I also try to use Simple message converter but still facing same issue ), If you will check below log trace  ActiveMQMessageConsumer is throwing this exception.

```
[nerContainer1-1] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : readerIndex(22) + length(20) exceeds writerIndex(38): UnpooledDuplicatedByteBuf(ridx: 22, widx: 38, cap: 221, unwrapped: UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 209, widx: 221, cap: 221))@ClientMessageImpl[messageID=3713, durable=true, address=jms.topic.exampleTopic,userID=c0b2a331-de72-11e7-ab14-3e1461f90711,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=4,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=0]]

        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(22) + length(20) exceeds writerIndex(38): UnpooledDuplicatedByteBuf(ridx: 22, widx: 38, cap: 221, unwrapped: UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 209, widx: 221, cap: 221))@ClientMessageImpl[messageID=3713, durable=true, address=jms.topic.exampleTopic,userID=c0b2a331-de72-11e7-ab14-3e1461f90711,properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=4,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=0]]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:230) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:132) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:130) ~[spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:416) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:302) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
        Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(22) + length(20) exceeds writerIndex(38): UnpooledDuplicatedByteBuf(ridx: 22, widx: 38, cap: 221, unwrapped: UnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 209, widx: 221, cap: 221))
            at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1395) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
            at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1389) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
            at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:850) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
            at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:858) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
            at io.netty.buffer.WrappedByteBuf.readBytes(WrappedByteBuf.java:649) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readSimpleStringInternal(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:93) ~[artemis-commons-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readNullableSimpleString(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:73) ~[artemis-commons-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.reader.TextMessageUtil.readBodyText(TextMessageUtil.java:37) ~[artemis-core-client-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQTextMessage.doBeforeReceive(ActiveMQTextMessage.java:112) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:224) ~[artemis-jms-client-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
            ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Seems like this is a question for the Artemis folks, not Spring. You are not using Spring on the producer side and the problem on the consumer side is in Artemis/Netty code. The converter makes no difference since the problem occurs before Spring gets the message.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell, I have updated question.

Comment: What version of Artemis are you using?  Can you provide a GitHub repo with a reproducible test-case?

Comment: @JustinBertram here is spring app https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/ApacheArtemisCluster/tree/durable-subscription-with-on-demand

and here is sample java program https://github.com/jbertram/activemq-artemis/blob/clustered-durable-subscription-static-discovery/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/StaticClusteredQueueExample.java  (I am using 2 nodes cluster )
Here is broker server broker.xml : https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/ApacheArtemisCluster/tree/durable-subscription-with-on-demand/broker

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more automated.  Could you modify one of the existing examples shipped with Artemis so that it will automatically configure the broker, start it, and run your client?  I've found it's generally a good idea to make it as easy as possible to reproduce an error when I need help so that those trying to help me don't have to spend a bunch of time and effort setting up the test-case.

Comment: Did you found the answer?

Comment: @NorbertoRitzmann ya there was dependencies issue, i have update dependencies then it work